# Backup MySQL users and permissions

Tags: mysql, backup

I'm setting up backup procedures on my server.  I'm going to backup all files, mysql databses, etc.  I'm wondering if there's a file or place I can backup in order to just be able to "restore" mysql users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mysql user is in the table user of database Mysql, for backup this table you could do this :

```
mysqldump -u root -p mysql user > UserTableBackup.sql
```

For backup all database of mysql and create a file for each database you could do your own shell script, following some line of code that can help you :

```
    # Get all database list first
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS -Bse 'show databases')"

echo `date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S` - Backup Mysql Database Started >> /home/Backup/Backup.log 
for db in $DBS
do
    skipdb=-1
    if [ "$IGGY" != "" ];
    then
    for i in $IGGY
    do
        [ "$db" == "$i" ] && skipdb=1 || :
    done
    fi

    if [ "$skipdb" == "-1" ] ; then
    FILE="$MBD/$db.$HOST.$NOW.gz"
    # do all inone job in pipe,
    # connect to mysql using mysqldump for select mysql database
    # and pipe it out to gz file in backup dir :)
        echo `date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S` - Backup "$db.$HOST.$NOW.gz" Started  >> /home/Backup/Backup.log
        $MYSQLDUMP -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS --default-character-set=utf8 $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
        echo `date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S` - Backup "$db.$HOST.$NOW.gz" Completed !  >> /home/Backup/Backup.log
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql` database itself contains all the data needed to restore users and permissions. Just make sure your backup script backs up the `mysql` database and you should be able to restore it easily.

Comment: Do you know of any place I can get a good MySQL backup script that creates an individual file for each database?  Isn't it bad practice to backup the database itself?

Comment: Not at all! MySQL makes it easy to do so and it's encouraged. It allows you to restore a DB server to a fully functional state with a full backup. `automysqlbackup` has served me well in the past. I would suggest using that: http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/

Answer (score 0):

backup a file you get by running "mysqldump mysql >filename"

Answer (score 0):

In Addition the other answers, You can use this script just to export all of your users and their privileges except the `root` user:

```
mysql -BNe "select concat('\'',user,'\'@\'',host,'\'') from mysql.user where user != 'root'" | \
while read uh; do mysql -BNe "show grants for $uh" | sed 's/$/;/; s/\\\\/\\/g'; done > grants.sql
```

So, TNX to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9410698/926639